# Batch cmd line - amend string in FOR /F for later use

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm struggling with amending the contents of a variable generated out of a for command.

I have the following code which works

```
set locn=E:\oracle\Logging\
set archlocn=E:\oracle\Logging\Archive\
set newstr=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set newstr=%newstr: =0%
set str=
set str1=

FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims= " %%j in (servicesa.txt) do (set str=%%j)
```

the value of `str` is something like `mydomain_network_test_JE` and I wish to create another string which strips out then `mydomain_` and appends `_stdout.txt` once that is done then I also need to use the new string (known as `str1`) in the following lines of code for each entry in my file servicesa.txt

```
copy "%locn%%str1%" "%archlocn%%str1:~0,16%_%newstr%%str1:~-4%"
del "%locn%%str1%"
```

So what I'm failing to achieve is the conversion from `str` to `str1` and get them all working under the same do command

btw I have worked out that the conversion from `str` to `str1` is something like

```
SET str1=%str:~9% but I can't get this to recognise the variable str
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `delayedexpansion`.

To replace your string you can use a second FOR /F loop like this :

```
@echo off
set locn=E:\oracle\Logging\
set archlocn=E:\oracle\Logging\Archive\
set newstr=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
set newstr=%newstr: =0%
set str1=

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims= " %%a in (servicesa.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2* delims=_" %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
     set "str1=%%b_%%c_stdout.txt"
     echo copy "%locn%!str1!" "%archlocn%%str1:~0,16%_%newstr%!str1!"
     echo del "%locn%!str1!"
   )
 )
```

**Note that** i putted an `echo` before the `copy` and `Del`commands, so you can check the output without any damage on your files.

If the output is OK just remove it

Comment: I recommend putting the setlocal before you set file specific environment strings unless you need them to be passed to the calling or child batch files.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, sorry about the delay in replying with thanks, I managed to figure out I needed Delayed Expansion, but didn't spot the neatness of the second for loop.